# pug mixin inside input type attribute

Tags: pug

I have this `pug mixin`. My question is how do I replace `1` with id parameter?

```
mixin workExperience(id, position, company, dateFrom, dateTo)
  section#work
    section.work-item
      input.toggle-item(id='work-item-1' type='checkbox' checked='checked')
      label(for='work-item-1')
      header
        .position= position
        .company= company
        .date
          span.startDate= dateFrom
          span.endDate= dateTo
```

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate a string and the `id` parameter with the [addition operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition), like you would do in JavaScript:

```
input.toggle-item(id='work-item-' + id type='checkbox' checked='checked')
label(for='work-item-' + id)
```

It might be clearer to use a comma between the attributes or to wrap the `id` attribute's value in parentheses, especially in the first case:

```
input.toggle-item(id='work-item-' + id, type='checkbox', checked='checked')

input.toggle-item(id=('work-item-' + id) type='checkbox' checked='checked')
```

All three options produce the same result, but the last two are more readable than the first one.

---

Another option is to use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
input.toggle-item(id=`work-item-${id}` type='checkbox' checked='checked')
label(for=`work-item-${id}`)
```

I think I like this option the most.